# Normally distributed random function without irrational operations

Tags: random, normal-distribution

I'm working on a game for which I want deterministic demo playback that is portable between architectures that treat floating point numbers differently. I'm using the Racket language, which conveniently has, as a primitive data type, non-floating-point representations of rational-number fractions. I want to use these to implement an approximately normally-distributed random function that accepts parameters for mean and standard deviation (skewness would be gold-plating).

Because of the limitations I've mentioned, any operation that takes in rational numbers and puts out irrational ones will need to be reimplemented from scratch in a way that produces approximations based on Racket's native fractions, *not* based on floating points. I've looked around at various algorithms for normal random functions, but of these, even many of the "simplest" ones like the Box-Muller transform involve things like square roots, logarithms, and trig functions. Iterated averaging is easy, so square roots aren't a problem, but I don't want to reinvent any more wheels than I need to here.

What are some algorithms I can use for generating approximately normal random numbers *without* invoking irrational operations like roots, logarithms, and trig functions?

Answer (score 2):

I settled on a solution after typing up this question but before sending it, so I'll Share My Knowledge Q&A-Style.

After poring over several different SO posts on normally-distributed random numbers, I found that the best solution for my purposes was actually the most naive one: abuse the Central Limit Theorem. Random variables of any distribution, when added up, approximate a normal distribution just fine. In Racket, my solution turned out to be the delightfully concise

```
(define (random/normal μ σ)
  (+ (* (- (for/sum ([i 12])
                    (random/uniform 0 1))
           6)
        σ)
     μ))
```

where `uniform-random` is my function for generating uniformly random rational numbers.
In infix, imperative pseudocode, this means:

```
Function random_normal(μ, σ):
  iterations := 12
  sum := 0
  for i from 1 to iterations:
    sum += random_uniform(0, 1)
  sum -= iterations / 2          # center the distribution on 0
  return σ * sum + μ
```

### Why 12 iterations?

A few SO answers mention this solution, but don't explain why 12 is a magic number here. When we add up those numbers, **we want the standard deviation of that random sum to equal 1** so that we can stretch out or squish down the bell curve by the desired amount in a single multiplicative step.

If you sum a sample of random variables [image: X_1, X_2,...,X_N,] the standard deviation of the approximately normal distribution this creates is equal to

[image: σ_xN/sqrt(12)]

where [image: σ_x] is the standard deviation of the variables themselves.<sup>*</sup> The standard deviation of a uniform random distribution from 0 to 1 is equal to [image: 1/sqrt(12)]<sup>†</sup> so by substituting this in for [image: σ_x,] we see that what we want is just

[image: N/sqrt(12N)=1,]

which works out easily to [image: N=12.]

<sup>*</sup> See ["Central Limit Theorem"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralLimitTheorem.html) on Wolfram MathWorld. Equation is given under identity (2), here multiplied by *N* to give the standard deviation of the sum rather than of the average.

<sup>†</sup> See ["Continuous uniform distribution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) on Wikipedia. Table on the right, "variance" [image: (σ^2),] square-rooted.

### But doesn't this limit your range to ±6 standard deviations?

It does, but the range of your distribution has to be truncated somewhere unless you have infinite memory, and ±6σ is A) [almost as good as Box-Muller on a 32-bit machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform#Tails_truncation) and B) already huge.